Count the users that have clicked at least one of an events set in Looker Studio
I am using Looker Studio with a GA4 analytics property.
I have a series of events hit by users (event1, event2, event3) some of them have a parameter that needs to be taken into consideration for the event to make sense (event4&param1=A).
To see the active users that have hit each event, I created 4 separate filter with Include event name = event1, etc and for the param specific Include eventname = event4 & param1=a (the param1 is created as a custom dimension).
What I want to calculate is the number of users that have hit any of the events.
So for example:
User 1 hits: event1, event2
User 2 hits: event4 & param1=a, event1
User 3 hits: event3
That would make 3 users.
I have used the following methods, unsucessfully:

Regex filter (event1|event2|event3) -> doesn't work because of the parameter addition. It can work for standalone events but not for events & params (or I don't know how to do it)
Cross join the 4 metrics -> it returns only the value of the first event

How could I calculate it?
